# How to make social sharing buttons display as inline block using CSS?

Tags: html, css, optimization, facebook-social-plugins

I have some social sharing buttons (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn) that I currently have displayed in inline-block format, which I prefer. However, the way I go about this - using YUI's for each individual button for every post - has really bloated my CSS. I'd like to accomplish this by simply using CSS class selectors, to optimize things a bit. Currently, the stylizing process is extremely tedious.

I'm using HTML/JS buttons, the code supplied by the developer websites of each platform. However, I haven't been able to find the right combination of selectors to make any new code effective. Any help with doing so would be great.

Button code:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com/international-pulse/opinion-we-must-win-the-battle-against-climate-change" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="false">
    <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tylercharboneauprofessional.com%2Finternational-pulse%2Fopinion-we-must-win-the-battle-against-climate-change&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
</div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
```

Current button groups (FB, Twitter, LinkedIn) are styled as follows, respectively:

```
padding-top: 0, padding-bottom: 0 /
padding-top: 12px, padding-bottom: 5px /
padding-top: 0, padding-bottom: 5px
```

Comment: Please include your  code to date, preferably as a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example. Group you social items, then apply the required styles to the items in the group. You can apply any other common styling in this way.

```css
/*Common Styling*/
.social-group>.social-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*Facebook specific*/
.social-group>.social-item.facebook {
   padding-top: 0, padding-bottom: 0
}

/*Twitter Specific*/
.social-group>.social-item.twitter {
    padding-top: 12px, padding-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="social-group">
  <div class="fb-share-button social-item facebook" data-href="https://www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com/international-pulse/opinion-we-must-win-the-battle-against-climate-change" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="false">
    <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tylercharboneauprofessional.com%2Finternational-pulse%2Fopinion-we-must-win-the-battle-against-climate-change&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
  </div>

  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button social-item twitter" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
</div>


<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
```

If you have limited access to modifying the html you can use a selector list to provide common styling. HTML grouping is not required for this.

```
.fb-share-button, .twitter-share-button {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Or if all media items have a class structured like `something-share-button` you could use an attribute selector:

```
[class*='-share-button']  {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

This will select **anything** with a class containing *-share-button*. This approach is probably too fragile though.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's worth noting that in my case, I'm working within the confines of a Squarespace site. The code for my buttons lives within individual code blocks; since I have three different share buttons, there are three code blocks following each blog post. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of working with a free form HTML document that I have assembled from the ground up. For clarification, wouldn't that render grouping the elements unworkable?

Comment: Can you add and change classes on elements?

Comment: I really don't have much experience in that area, at least for this project I've been working on. Typically, traditional CSS rules apply anywhere you wish to apply them within my site; it's important to keep in mind, however, that I do not have access to Squarespace's core HTML structure for modifying the template (unless by unlocking "Developer Mode", but that's beyond my scope of expertise). Beyond adding pseudo classes to navigation elements and the like, I typically use Safari dev tools to "hunt" for element classes as they exist, and then alter properties from there.

Comment: If you are unable to modify the HTML in any way, it will make optimisation very difficult.

Comment: Correct. To me when monkeying around with this, I would have guessed the classes for the buttons to be "fb-share-button", "twitter-share-button", and "IN-widget" - based on the HTML provided, and doing a little digging. Based on the code, and maybe using developer tools, would you come to a similar conclusion @Jon P ?